# How to work on tkinter code and split in multiple files

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I was writing code with tkinter, and the whole code was in single file, but I successed to split in multiple files. There are two files `main.py` and `MyFirstpanel.py`. when I click on button it runs `MyFirstPanel.py` file. when I click on button then it goes back to `main.py`. but again I want to go to `MyFirstPanel.py` file it gives me an error.

#### `Error`

```
myFirstPanel = MyFirstPanel(self.root)
NameError: name 'MyFirstPanel' is not defined
Exception in Tkinter callback
```

My code looks like this

#### `main.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from MyFirstPanel import *


class MyTkWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root  # Makes the window
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.root, width=500, height=500)
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

        self.user_login_btn = Button(self.mainFrame, text='Go To First Frame', relief='solid', font=('times new roman', 11),
                                     height=1, width=6, command=self.gotofirstpanel)
        self.user_login_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=30, sticky=(N, S, E, W))


    def gotofirstpanel(self):
        self.mainFrame.destroy()
        myFirstPanel = MyFirstPanel(self.root)
        myFirstPanel.start()

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    myWindow = MyTkWindow(root)
    myWindow.start()
```

#### `MyFirstPanel.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from main import *

class MyFirstPanel:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.root, width=500, height=500)
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
        self.user_login_btn = Button(self.mainFrame, text='First Panels', relief='solid', font=('times new roman', 15),
                                     height=1, width=6, command=self.gotomainpanel)
        self.user_login_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=10, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

    def gotomainpanel(self):
        self.mainFrame.destroy()
        myTkWindow = MyTkWindow(self.root)
        myTkWindow.start()
        self.root.destroy()


    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wouldnt this lead to circular import? Post the entire error code please.

Comment: Complete error is given on top

Comment: That is not the complete error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I changed `from MyFirstPanel import *` to `import MyFirstPanel` and `MyFirstPanel(self.root)` to `MyFirstPanel.MyFirstPanel(self.root)`

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
import MyFirstPanel


class MyTkWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root  # Makes the window
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.root, width=500, height=500)
        self.mainFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

        self.user_login_btn = Button(self.mainFrame, text='Go To First Frame',     relief='solid', font=('times new roman', 11),
                                     height=1, width=6, command=self.gotofirstpanel)
        self.user_login_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=30, sticky=(N, S, E, W))


    def gotofirstpanel(self):
        self.mainFrame.destroy()
        myFirstPanel = MyFirstPanel.MyFirstPanel(self.root)
        myFirstPanel.start()

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    myWindow = MyTkWindow(root)
    myWindow.start()
```